# displaying data in the same page on form submission

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I need to create a table on the same page when the submit button is clicked .. How do I do it using jQuery .. The table is created in a new page on submitting a form .. Plz help ..

Comment: You're looking to do this with AJAX?  What are you stuck on?  More information is needed to provide you a useful answer.

Comment: No I need to do it using jQuery ..

Comment: you need to click the button and then the table will be created with some values in it and all this in the same page?

Comment: I have a set of checkboxes .. Clicking on the checkboxes will display the details in a table .. The table is formed on the new page .. But I need it in the same page .. How do I do it using jQuery ..

Comment: @themhz .. Exactly that's wat I want ..

Comment: @shaz, Is your question about getting the data or building a table in the DOM?  If you already have the data, then show an example.  If you need to know how to get the data, then post a URL to that data, and an example of what the response is.

Comment: Gettin the data on the table works very fine .. But I need the table on the same page ..

Comment: @shaz, You aren't listening.  **What is your question, specifically?**  Do you need to know how to add elements to the DOM with jQuery?  Or do you need to know how to get data from the server over AJAX?  Or, is your data already available to your application within the page itself?

Comment: I need to know how to add elements to the dom with jQuery ..

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
//$(document).ready(function() {
function submitbutton()
{
  $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>my data</td><td>more data</td></tr>');
  $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>my data</td><td>more data</td></tr>');
  $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>my data</td><td>more data</td></tr>');
  $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>my data</td><td>more data</td></tr>');
  $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>my data</td><td>more data</td></tr>');
  $('#myTable').show();
 }
//});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable" style="display:none;border:1px solid #000000;"></table>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="submitbutton()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: here is also a jqeury tutorial about appending html tables
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/create-html-table-dynamically

Comment: and some more here http://www.packtpub.com/article/using-jquery-script-for-creating-dynamic-table-of-contents